# Binding trigonometric terms

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have many terms like

```
A = Cos[Pi/18 + 2 x] + Cos[Pi/18 - 2 x]
```

and I want to convert `A` to

```
2 Cos[Pi/18] Cos[2 x]
```

automatically.

How can I do this?

What I can get by `Simplify[A]` is `-(-1)^(17/18) (1 + (-1)^(1/9)) Cos[2 x]`, but I don't like these exponential terms.

Comment: Try terms/.A->(2 Cos[Pi/18] Cos[2 x])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    A = (Cos[Pi/18 + 2 x] + Cos[Pi/18 - 2 x] /. Pi -> pi // Simplify) /. 
  pi -> \[Pi]

(*    2 Cos[\[Pi]/18] Cos[2 x]   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can use TrigExpand and then Simplify:

```
TrigExpand[Cos[Pi/18 + 2 x] + Cos[Pi/18 - 2 x]] // Simplify

(* 2 Cos[\[Pi]/18] Cos[2 x] *)
```